# Access a UIView's properties on a background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, collectionview

I am trying to have my CollectionView scroll it's first cell after the view appears, and then again whenever a button is pressed.  The problem is that the collectionView hasn't generated all it's cells at any of the view lifecycle functions.

My solution is to beging a while loop on a background thread that checks to see if `collectionView.visibleCells.count > 0`, and when it is, return to the main thread and scroll to the first cell.  However, I get an error, telling me that I shouldn't access `visibleCells` off the main thread, and the app chugs when I do.

How can I achieve this functionality on the main thread, or check the number of cells in the background thread?

```
private func scrollToFirst() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        if (self != nil) {
            while(self!.collectionView.visibleCells.count != 0) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self!.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why your colllectionview wouldn't already be displaying the first cell when the view appears. You are probably thinking about this the wrong way; what you need to do is reload or scroll the collection view when your data source model changes.

Comment: You know when the data is available to the collection view so you know when the cells are about to be rendered. And you know when a specific cell is rendered through the collection view's delegate. With these two pieces of information, you can easily construct a mechanism to notify you when you need to be notified.

Comment: @Paulw11 if the underlying data source is asynchronous, then no cells would be visible when the view appears.

Comment: Yes, but when you reload the view after the data is available, it will be showing the first cell. As you and I both said, they need to tackle this from the data source side, not the view side.

Comment: @Paulw11 It's not centered when I change section sizes/data.

Comment: Ok, but you still have “the tail wagging the dog” trying to work out when the view is in a certain state. When the data changes, you should trigger the redraw of the view. You can dispatch that onto the main thread if the data change happens on another thread. You need to explain your actual problem more clearly and perhaps show more code. At the moment you are describing a problem that arises due to your attempt to fix the actual,problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delegate method [willDisplay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc) that gets called right before a collectionViewCell gets displayed.  If you previously had no cells and this gets called, then you know you are about to go from zero to more than zero cells.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't do that. UIKit is not thread-safe, so the data structures of view objects may change out from under you when you try to view them from a background threads.

It seems like there should be a better way to deal with this than waiting for cells to appear.

If you can't figure out a cleaner way to do it, you could use a Timer object, which runs on the main thread. That code might look something like this:

```
private func scrollToFirst(afterDelay delay: Double = 0.2) {
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false) { 
        timer, [weak self] in
        guard strongSelf = self else {
          return
        }
        if strongSelf.collectionView.visibleCells.count != 0 {
          self!.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
}
```

That code would fire once, and scroll to the beginning of the collection view if there are once the timer fires.

Comment: I thought about this, but i'm looking for a cleaner solution.  I can't find any function that gets fired once the collectionView has gone from 0 cells to more than 0 cells.

Comment: Yes it's a bit of a hack, but it's a helluva lot better than trying to query UIKit objects from a background thread.